# Config Apache to Use VPS as a Browser Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, centos, vps

I am from a country with severe internet censorship. I want to surf the internet freely.

I have a VPS installed with CentOS5.5 and Apache 2 in U.S. Assume the VPS has the IP `12.34.56.78`.

I want to config it as a browser proxy, like this: `12.34.56.78:8080`. (I know how to use the ssh method, but I want to config the VPS as a browser proxy. Put `12.34.56.78:8080` in the browser Firefox, then I can surf the internet freely.)

I have found this link:http://www.vo1dmain.info/how-to-configure-private-proxy-on-vps.But It requires ssh client on your home computer. And I have dynamic IP, by the way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting, I would suspect you'd need to run a proxy on your VPS. try an app called squid. Let me know if you want further details.  Basically you'd want to do an apt-get or yum install squid, then google squid proxy server to configure it. Webmin has a good console you can use

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply. Cant Apache do this job? I want to have some thing like this:http://www.ip-adress.com/proxy_list/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through Apache; the link you posted tells you how. Here's another one: http://www.enterpriseitplanet.com/networking/features/article.php/11315_3319671_1

And you have several options for your dynamic IP:

```
  Order Deny, Allow 
  Deny from all 
  Allow from 192.168.1 .mcslp.pri
```

You can specify multiple entries made up for IP prefix, domain name, IP address subnets, and IPv6 addresses and subnets. As shown here, it is preferable to specify an IP address and domain, just to be sure *(from the posted url)*.

And you'll need an ssh client... grab putty if you're on Windows.